# How can I add items into a java list using strings?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a school project but i got stuck. Basically, i have to do a drugstore where you log in and u have to select an item from the java list and then buy it.

Login code:

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.lang.Object;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    public Login() {
        initComponents();

        //placeholder pt username
        final String placeholderUsername = "Username";
        jUsername.setText(placeholderUsername);    
        jUsername.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
    private boolean showingPlaceholder = true;
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    if (showingPlaceholder) {
                            showingPlaceholder = false;
                            jUsername.setText("");
                    }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    if (jUsername.getText().isEmpty()) {
                            jUsername.setText(placeholderUsername);
                            showingPlaceholder = true;
                    }
            }
        });

        //placeholder pt parola
        final String placeholderParola = "Parola";
        jParola.setText(placeholderParola);    
        jParola.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
    private boolean showingPlaceholder = true;
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    if (showingPlaceholder) {
                            showingPlaceholder = false;
                            jParola.setText("");
                    }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    if (jParola.getText().isEmpty()) {
                            jParola.setText(placeholderParola);
                            showingPlaceholder = true;
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFereastraLogin = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jUsername = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jParola = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButonLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButonCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jFereastraLogin.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        jFereastraLogin.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Login"));
        jFereastraLogin.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 400));
        jFereastraLogin.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jUsername.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        jUsername.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10, 20));
        jUsername.setSelectedTextColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jUsername.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jFereastraLogin.add(jUsername, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 50, 300, 25));

        jParola.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        jParola.setSelectedTextColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jParola.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jFereastraLogin.add(jParola, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 100, 300, 25));

        jButonLogin.setText("Login");
        jButonLogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButonLoginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jFereastraLogin.add(jButonLogin, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(70, 140, 100, 20));

        jButonCancel.setText("Cancel");
        jButonCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButonCancelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jFereastraLogin.add(jButonCancel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(220, 140, 100, 20));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jFereastraLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jFereastraLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButonCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        System.exit(0);
    }                                            

    private void jButonLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String uname=jUsername.getText();
        String pword=jParola.getText();
        if(uname.equals("admin") && pword.equals("admin")){
            Home ho=new Home();
            ho.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }
        else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Username sau parola incorecte");
        }
    }                                           

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButonCancel;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButonLogin;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jFereastraLogin;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jParola;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jUsername;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This one works fine. After u log in you got redirected to homepage:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Home extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Home() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFereastraLogin = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPlafar = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jListaPlante = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jButtonCumpara = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jFereastraLogin.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        jFereastraLogin.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Home"));
        jFereastraLogin.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPlafar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jPlafar.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jPlafar.setText("PLAFAR");
        jFereastraLogin.add(jPlafar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 10, 580, 30));

        jListaPlante.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jListaPlante.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>(){
            String[] listaplante = new String[10];

            public void citeste(){
                System.out.println("daaaa");
                /*int c;
                int k=0;
                String planta = "";
                FileReader f = null;
                try {
                    f = new FileReader("Plante.txt");
                    while ((c = f.read()) != -1) {
                        planta = planta + (char)c; // formez numele plantei
                    }
                    listaplante[k] = planta;
                    k++;
                    planta = "";
                    f.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fisierul nu a fost gasit");
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Eroare la citire");
                }
                */

                BufferedReader objReader = null;
                int k=0;
                try {
                    String strCurrentLine;
                    objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Plante.txt"));
                    while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
                        listaplante[k] = strCurrentLine;
                        k++;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (objReader != null)
                        objReader.close();
                    }catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
            public int getSize() { return listaplante.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return listaplante[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jListaPlante);

        jFereastraLogin.add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 90, 560, 50));

        jButtonCumpara.setText("CUMPARA");
        jButtonCumpara.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonCumparaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jFereastraLogin.add(jButtonCumpara, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 160, -1, -1));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jFereastraLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jFereastraLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 375, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButtonCumparaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    }                                              


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Home().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonCumpara;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jFereastraLogin;
    public javax.swing.JList<String> jListaPlante;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jPlafar;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Can somebody explain me why the function "citeste()" doesn't work? I'm trying to read from a file the medical plants and then put them into a array of strings. The thing is that when i run the project(GUI), this array of strings looks like its not linked to the jList. The list is just empty.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: can you please explain what the functionality of citesite() is and perhaps also the contents of Plante.txt? Is it only the commented section you need assistance with? Also what errors are you receiving?

Comment: in citeste() im trying to read from Plante.txt and add the strings into an array of strings. The commented section is a way to do it but its kinda buggy so i tried to read from file with BufferedReader. Im not receiving any error the only thing is that the jlist(made with netbeans giu explorer or whatever the name is) is empty.

Comment: Plante means Plants.

Comment: oh i forgot, Plante.txt its somethink like one word per line

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.   I advise you to try and break this down.  You report that the jlist doesn't contain your array of strings.  Try to reproduce that with as little code as possible - you'll find where you're failing to link them.  Or you could try proving to yourself that that you are actually successfully populating the array of strings.

Comment: @CPerkins im trying but im not succesful idk what to do anymore. im so new to java and this project is for graduating at this subject so its kinda hard when your teacher doesnt help you

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your method citeste is never called.

I tweaked your code a little to initiate the jlist with the listaplante array.

You are trying to add values in the set model of jlist, which doesnt look very clean.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    public class Home extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public Home() {
            initComponents();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jFereastraLogin = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jPlafar = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();

            jButtonCumpara = new javax.swing.JButton();

            String[] listaplante = new String[10];
            BufferedReader objReader = null;
                    int k=0;
                    try {
                        String strCurrentLine;
                        objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Plante.txt"));
                        while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
                            listaplante[k] = strCurrentLine;
                            k++;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (objReader != null)
                            objReader.close();
                        }catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            jListaPlante = new javax.swing.JList<>(listaplante);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jFereastraLogin.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
            jFereastraLogin.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Home"));
            jFereastraLogin.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

            jPlafar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
            jPlafar.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            jPlafar.setText("PLAFAR");
            jFereastraLogin.add(jPlafar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 10, 580, 30));

            jListaPlante.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
            jListaPlante.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>(){
                public int getSize() { return listaplante.length; }
                public String getElementAt(int i) { return listaplante[i]; }
            });
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jListaPlante);

            jFereastraLogin.add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 90, 560, 50));

            jButtonCumpara.setText("CUMPARA");
            jButtonCumpara.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButtonCumparaActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
            jFereastraLogin.add(jButtonCumpara, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 160, -1, -1));

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jFereastraLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jFereastraLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 375, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void jButtonCumparaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

        }                                              


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Home().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButtonCumpara;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jFereastraLogin;
        public javax.swing.JList<String> jListaPlante;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jPlafar;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Comment: the thing is that i dont have general access to write where i want thats why the reading from file was in a method with all other method from jlist. If i make a button for exemple using the netBeans GUI the code write itself

Answer (score 0):

Your method `citeste` is never called, thus your list is empty
You should populate the list in constructor or check that the list is empty in your inherited methods `getSize` and `getElementAt` and call your `citeste` from there. Make sure you do not enter into infinite loop though :)
And you should annotate your getSize and getElementAt with @Override.
You could modify your inner class to something like the following:

```
jListaPlante.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>(){
            String[] listaplante = new String[10];
            Boolean isInitialized = false;

            private void citeste(){
                System.out.println("daaaa");
                /*int c;
                int k=0;
                String planta = "";
                FileReader f = null;
                try {
                    f = new FileReader("Plante.txt");
                    while ((c = f.read()) != -1) {
                        planta = planta + (char)c; // formez numele plantei
                    }
                    listaplante[k] = planta;
                    k++;
                    planta = "";
                    f.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fisierul nu a fost gasit");
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Eroare la citire");
                }
                */

                BufferedReader objReader = null;
                int k=0;
                try {
                    String strCurrentLine;
                    objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Plante.txt"));
                    while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
                        listaplante[k] = strCurrentLine;
                        k++;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (objReader != null)
                        objReader.close();
                    }catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
            public int getSize() {
                if (!isInitialized) {
                    citeste();
                    isInitialized = true;
                }
                return listaplante.length; 
            }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { 
                if (!isInitialized) {
                    citeste();
                    isInitialized = true;
                }
                return listaplante[i]; 
            }
        });
```

Comment: getSize and getElementAt where predefined when i created the jList with swing buttons. So how should i write the consturctor myself and get rid of citeste method?